# How to extract values from a nested dict_values object

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a dict_values object. When i read it:

```
Info = mydata.values()
```

and I display it, it shows as follow:

```
dict_values([{'loc': -1392.9605288965874, 'scale': 652.5001331690878}])
```

My goal is to generate a numpy array extracting the values in the dict_values object, so:

```
array([-1392.9605288965874, 652.5001331690878])
```

The problem is that I'm still not able to 'separate' the text information, so for instance, the description of the parameters ('loc' and 'scale').

How can I do it?

Comment: Try `np.array([[x['loc'], x['scale']] for x in Info])`

Comment: Exaclty what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use .values() twice and obtain the array without defining the inner dict keynames:

```
out = np.array([x for y in mydata.values() for x in y.values()])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get that `values` `mydata` must have been a dict itself, something like:

```
In [46]: d={'foobar':{'loc': -1392.9605288965874, 'scale': 652.5001331690878}}
In [47]: d
Out[47]: {'foobar': {'loc': -1392.9605288965874, 'scale': 652.5001331690878}}
```

Then its values:

```
In [48]: d.values()
Out[48]: dict_values([{'loc': -1392.9605288965874, 'scale': 652.5001331690878}])
```

expand that into a list, and select the one item:

```
In [49]: list(d.values())
Out[49]: [{'loc': -1392.9605288965874, 'scale': 652.5001331690878}]
In [50]: list(d.values())[0]
Out[50]: {'loc': -1392.9605288965874, 'scale': 652.5001331690878}
```

That's a dict, so we can again get the values:

```
In [51]: list(d.values())[0].values()
Out[51]: dict_values([-1392.9605288965874, 652.5001331690878])
```

and make an array from the derived list:

```
In [53]: np.array(list(list(d.values())[0].values()))
Out[53]: array([-1392.9605289 ,   652.50013317])
```

with just one element in the outer dict, it may be simpler to select that by key rather than values:

```
In [54]: d['foobar']
Out[54]: {'loc': -1392.9605288965874, 'scale': 652.5001331690878}
```

The main challenge with nested structures like this is keeping track of what you have at each level.

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```
values_dict = list(Info)[0]
values_list = [v for k, v in values_dict.items()]
numpy_array = np.array(values_list)

print(numpy_array)
```